# New project created with Flex Mojo's archetype throws Cannot Find Parent Project-Maven Exception

Tags: java, apache-flex, maven-2, flexmojos, flex-mojos

This is probably a silly question but I just cant seem to figure out. I'm completely new to flex and maven.

Maven 2.2.1: Maven 2.2.1 unzipped,M2_HOME set and repository altered to point to different drive location in `settings.xml`

Flex 4.0: Installed

Created a multi-modular webapp project using flexmojo:

```
mvn archetype:generate
-DarchetypeRepository=http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup 
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.sonatype.flexmojos 
-DarchetypeArtifactId=flexmojos-archetypes-modular-webapp 
-DarchetypeVersion=RELEASE
```

with following options

```
groupId=com.test
artifactId=test
version=1.0-snapshot
package=com.tests
```

*** Creates ***

```
test
|-- pom.xml
|--swc -pom.xml
|--swf -pom.xml
`--war -pom.xml
```

Parent pom has swc, swf, war as modules.

Dependency is war->swf->swc.

With parent artifactId of swf, swc, war set to swf, swc, test respectively.

On executing mvn on test folder(for that matter clean or anything) I get this following error.

```
G:\Projects\test>mvn -e
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/test/swc/1.0-snapshot/swc-1.0-snapshot.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.test:swc:pom:1.0-snapshot' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

GroupId: com.test
ArtifactId: swc
Version: 1.0-snapshot

Reason: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  com.test:swc:pom:1.0-snapshot

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)



[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.reactor.MavenExecutionException: Cannot find parent: com.test:swc for project: com.test:swc-swc:swc:1.0-snapshot for project com.test:swc-swc:swc:1.0-snapshot
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjects(DefaultMaven.java:404)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:272)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Cannot find parent: com.test:swc for project: com.test:swc-swc:swc:1.0-snapshot for project com.test:swc-swc:swc:1.0-snapshot
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.assembleLineage(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1396)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:823)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromSourceFileInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:508)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.build(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProject(DefaultMaven.java:604)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:487)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:560)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjects(DefaultMaven.java:391)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: POM 'com.test:swc' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  com.test:swc:pom:1.0-snapshot

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

 for project com.test:swc
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.findModelFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:605)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.assembleLineage(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1392)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactNotFoundException: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  com.test:swc:pom:1.0-snapshot

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)


        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:228)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:90)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.findModelFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:558)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.ResourceDoesNotExistException: Unable to download the artifact from any repository
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.manager.DefaultWagonManager.getArtifact(DefaultWagonManager.java:404)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
        ... 22 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jun 15 19:22:15 GMT+02:00 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 1M/2M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Looks like its trying to download the project from maven's central repository instead of building it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to see without all the POM's.

However he parent relationship should not follow the dependencies.

All war,swf and swc should have the same parent, namely the pom.xml in the test directory.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you run `mvn install` from the root directory:

```
G:\Projects\test>mvn install
```